# Qt compiler error: 'emit' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a Simple GUI which creates multiple threads and perform some operation at the background while the GUI being responsive all the time. I am using QThreads of QT framework to achieve this but I am facing above said issue. Below is the code.

//Threading.h
This is my threading.h file.

```
#ifndef THREADING
#define THREADING

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>

class Threading : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
   int num;

public:
    explicit Threading(QObject * parent = 0);
    void run();
    void set_num(int);
    int get_num();

Q_SIGNALS:
    void someSignal(int);

};
```

//This is threading.cpp file

```
#include "threading.h"
#include <QtCore>

Threading::Threading(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
{

}

void Threading:: run()
{
  emit someSignal(get_num());
}

void Threading :: set_num(int num)
{
    QMutex mutex;
    mutex.lock();
    this->num = num;
    mutex.unlock();
}

int Threading :: get_num()
{
    return num;
}
```

//Mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include "threading.h"

typedef unsigned char   byte;

namespace Ui {
 class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Threading *threadPointer;
};
```

//Mainwindow.cpp
In this file I am starting thread.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "global.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui-> setupUi(this);
   threadPointer = new Threading(this);
   connect(threadPointer,SIGNAL(someSignal(int)),this,SLOT(onSomeSignal()));
 }

void MainWindow::on_clicked()
{
    threadPointer->set_num(0);
    threadPointer->start();    
}
```

I saw some video online which has exactly similar code which is strangely but working fine and mine is not. Does it have to do with version ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to what I see, `get_num()`  and `set_num()` use `num`, but I do not see anywhere that you have defined `num` in Threading.h

Comment: It looks like that `private: int number;` shall be `private: int num;`

Comment: @eyllanesc It was a typo. I have edited it now.

Comment: @Alex44 thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bypass the issue using `Q_EMIT` in place of `emit`, or just call the signal as a normal function (`emit` is optional and is there just for code readability):

```
void Threading:: run()
{
  someSignal(get_num());
}
```

`emit` is an empty macro defined in *qobjectdefs.h*. You should investigate further, and try to understand why it is not defined (e.g. if `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` is defined somewhere and why).

You may also want to check if a

```
CONFIG += no_keywords
```

line exists in your pro file, as explained at the very end of [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: That was on target. It worked like charm. @p-a-o-l-o